# on button return id to show specific json react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, web-applications, jsx

I have a grid of boxes that fetched people's info from a JSON, each box have a button function that is from component 'CZButton', this button is included in "personlist" and it shows a pop up, I want to show the person's email inside the pop up , i am not sure how can i show a unique json item on each click, whatever i add in the pop up its shown on all the buttons, and what i want is to show specific details about the person once the button is clicked. I'm new to react and would appreciate the help. here is a sandbox snippet.

https://codesandbox.io/s/r5kz3jx3z4?fontsize=14&moduleview=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to this would be to extend the `CZButton` component so that it accepts a `person` property, by which the `person` data can then be rendered within the pop up dialog:

```
/* Adapted from your codesandbox sample */
class CZButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { open: false };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    let { toggle } = this.state;

    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };

  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {" "}
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>Show</button>
        <Drawer
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={this.toggle}
          onDrag={() => {}}
          onOpen={() => {}}
          allowClose={true}
          modalElementClass="modal"
          containerElementClass="my-shade"
          parentElement={document.body}
          direction="bottom" >
          {/* This render the contents of the `person` prop's `email` field in dialog */}
          <div>{this.props.person.email}</div>

          {/* This renders the contents of `person` prop in dialog */}
          <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.person)}</div>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Seeing that your `CZButton` now rendering the contents of the `person` prop, the change above would also require that you supply this data when rendering the `CZButton` in the `PersonList` component's `render()` method like so:

```
<div className="row">
      {console.log(items)}
      {items.map(item => (
        <Person
          className="person"
          Key={item.id.name + item.name.first}
          imgSrc={item.picture.large}
          Title={item.name.title}
          FName={item.name.first} >
          {/* Pass the "person item" into our new person prop when rendering each CZButton */ }
          <CZButton person={item} />
        </Person>
      ))}
    </div>
```

[Here is a forked copy of your original code](https://codesandbox.io/s/l5q36r313m) with the updates mentioned above for you to try out. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your `PersonList` component, as you `map` each of your items, you want to send the item's `email` as a prop to the `CZButton`, like this:

```
{items.map(item => (
            <Person
              className="person"
              Key={item.id.name + item.name.first}
              imgSrc={item.picture.large}
              Title={item.name.title}
              FName={item.name.first}
            >
              {" "}
              <CZButton email={item.email} />
            </Person>
          ))}
```

Now, each `CZButton` gets a prop called `email`. In, the `render` method of your `CZButton`, you will want the content of `Drawer` to look like this:

```
<Drawer ...>
  <div>{this.props.email || "No email address for this person."}</div>
</Drawer>
```

You can try this out to see if it works for you.